# elasticsearch: cluster coordinating node not exposing elasticsearch service

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have set up a 6 node (3 master + 3 data) cluster.

I have also set a 7th coordinating node just to expose `kibana`  as outlined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/production.html#load-balancing).

What is now the cluster endpoint?

In my `elasticsearch.yml`

```
cluster.name: es-staging

bootstrap.memory_lock: true
transport.host: 10.11.27.27
network.host: 127.0.0.1
discovery.ec2.endpoint: ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_ip
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2 
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
s3.client.default.endpoint: s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
transport.tcp.port: 9300
node.name: elastic-staging-coord
action.auto_create_index: true
```

and in my `kibana.yml`

```
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
server.port: 80
server.host: 10.11.27.27
```

However

```
$ curl -IL http://<public_ip_of_coordinating_node>:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <public_ip_of_coordinating_node> port 9200: Connection refused
```

What is now my cluster endpoint? Where all elasticsearch request be sent to?

cluster health is reported OK by the particular node btw

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "es-esa-staging",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 7,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1,
  "active_shards" : 2,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

( Ι am running `kibana` as `root` to be able to expose it to `80`)

**edit**: when switching to `0.0.0.0` as `network.host` setting, I get the following:

```
$ curl -IL http://<public_ip_or_coordinating_node>:9200
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 959
Connection: close
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

In the mean time:

```
 elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-12-12 08:08:24 UTC; 4min 39s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 9872 (java)
    Tasks: 52 (limit: 4704)
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           ├─9872 /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UT
           └─9952 /usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instance binds to 127.0.0.1 due to `network.host`setting[1]. So, your es instance accessible only for the localhost.

You should change this setting to some IP or hostname that accessible from your network.

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings

Comment: Yes but this is the recommended setting per the guidelines. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/production.html#load-balancing. What is more, I have tried changing it to `0.0.0.0` with no luck

Comment: in your kibana.yml, `server.host` param should be the IP that es bind  port 9200